# TouchedEnded over TouchesBegan - Swift iOS SpriteKit

Tags: swift, touch-event

I would have a touches began (which takes you to a separate scene) but i also have a SKSpriteNode setup in such as way that when you touch it you go to a different scene. This is my code for finding if the `settingsPage` node has been touched.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if (settingsPage .containsPoint(touchLocation))
    {
        println("Going to Settings")
        settingsScene()
    }   
}
```

for some reason the touches began takes priority over the touchesEnded.

Is their a way to get round this or?

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if (settingsPage .containsPoint(touchLocation))
    {
        println("Going to Settings")
        settingsScene()
   }






    game1 = 1

    if (Menu == 0) {
        movingObjects.speed = 1
        birdPhysics()
        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI), duration:0.8)
        bird.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))



        taptoflap.removeFromParent()

        started = 1

        if (powerupStatus == 1) {
            PUten = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8, target: self, selector: Selector("plustenSpawn"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

    }

    if (gameOver == 0) {




        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, impulse))



        // Add 1 to the currentTouches
        currentTouches++

        Menu = 1

    } else {
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
        settingsPage.removeFromParent()
        gameOver = 0                                                                                
        movingObjects.speed = 1
        // Animate Bird
        var animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([birdTexture, birdTexture2, birdTexture3, birdTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.08)
        var makeBirdFlap = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)
        bird.runAction(makeBirdFlap)
        bird.texture = birdDeadTexture
        normButton.removeFromSuperview()
        highscoreClassic.removeFromParent()

        let height = self.frame.size.height
        let width = self.frame.size.width

        var speedGameScene: SpeedGameScene = SpeedGameScene(size: CGSizeMake(width, height))
        var spriteView: SKView = self.view as SKView!
        var trans:SKTransition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.7)
        spriteView.presentScene(speedGameScene, transition: trans)

    }
}
```

Comment: `touchesBegan` will always be executed before `touchesEnded`. I didn't understand your problem?

Comment: Well i have a node that is on my scene and when i touch that node i want to navigate to another scene but the thing is the node is only shown when the game is over but the touchesBegan will run the game again (if the screen is tapped)? does that make more sense?

Comment: can you show the `touchesBegan` code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `return` after the code in the `touchesBegan` to not execute the rest of the code.

```
if (settingsPage.containsPoint(touchLocation))
{
    println("Going to Settings")
    settingsScene()
    return
}
```